# What element controls the color of the thin strip between JPanel and JTabbedPane tab

Tags: java, swing

I am experimenting with color schemes in my program. I can change the color of the panel and tabbed-pane tabs but there is a thin strip between them that stays the default color

**I have already tried** to change the background colors of the `Frame`, `content pane`, `tabbed-pane` (both normal background and selected background) and panel. I have even tried changing border colors however it has not fixed the problem

(The colors I am using are just to make it more visible and the following code has been taken from various parts of the same java file just to show the code I am using)

```java
//Panel
testPanel.setBackground(Color.red); 
testPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.green, 3));

//Content pane
Container cp = this.frame.getContentPane();
cp.setBackground(Color.magenta);

//TabbedPane
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", Color.green);
tabbedPane.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
tabbedPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
```

I hoped that the color of the background would flow seamlessly from the main panel and up into the active tabbed-pane header tab ( in this case it is shown by the red background and green 'test panel' background, in the real program it will be the one color) however it is separated and even all the way around by a thin default grey strip (between the black and green border on left, right and bottom side).

An image is linked below to show what I mean as I understand my description may not be very clear
[image: IMG]

**Minimal Working example**

Below, the gray area is between the blue panel with black border and the pink content pane border and below the tabs

```
public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        //create frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("minimal working code");
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.setBounds(200, 200, 500, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //change tabbedPane selection colour
        UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", Color.green);
        //create tabbed pane
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        tabbedPane.setBounds(30, 20, 400, 200);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

        //create test panels
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.add("Panel 1", panel1);
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Panel 2",panel2);

        //change colors of panel and tabbed pane background and border
        panel1.setBackground(Color.blue);
        tabbedPane.setBackground(Color.red);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.yellow);
        panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black,3));
        tabbedPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.pink,3));     

    }
```

[image: IMG]

Comment: It would help if you would provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.  You left out a lot of code.

Comment: Added it now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily get rid of this line:

```
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentBorderInsets", new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Preview:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I spent some time finding this.  Looks like someone beat me to it.

```java
      UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentBorderInsets",
            new InsetsUIResource(0, 0, 0, 0));
      UIManager.put("TabbedPane.borderHightlightColor", java.awt.Color.yellow); // tab
      // UIManager.put("TabbedPane.shadow", java.awt.Color.yellow);
      // UIManager.put("TabbedPane.tabAreaBackground", java.awt.Color.yellow);
      UIManager.put("TabbedPane.light", java.awt.Color.yellow); // tab
      // UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selectHighlight", java.awt.Color.yellow);
      // UIManager.put("TabbedPane.highlight", java.awt.Color.yellow);
      UIManager.put("TabbedPane.darkShadow", java.awt.Color.yellow);// tab
      // UIManager.put("TabbedPane.focus", java.awt.Color.yellow);
      // UIManager.put("TabbedPane.lightHighlight", Color.yellow);
      // UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selectHighlight", Color.yellow);
```

You can find more information on these at https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/JavaUIDefaults.txt

Comment: @johnthomsonn This may provide additional information.

Comment: thank you, I appreciate the time you put into this and i've also made use of the borderHighlightColor and bookmarked the link you sent me.